# Qtouch lib on the ATXMEGA32A4U-MH

Tags: avr

I have a project with the ATXMEGA32A4U, in which I want to use the Atmel lib Qtouch , the problem that I have is that the controller doesn't support the Qtouch Hardware, but when I saw the other uC given in the example projects, the don't support the Qtouch Hardware too. So I'm confuesed now about the meaning of this support ,and my question is can implement a software solution using the Qtouch lib on this uC or no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTouch is a software touch solution, not hardware. It is dependent on basic MCU functionality in order to work.

According to the [product page](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATXMEGA32A4U.aspx) the ATxmega32A4U does have 16 touch channels and the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8387-8-and16-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-XMEGA-A4U_Datasheet.pdf) does mention "QTouch ® library support" with "capacitive touch buttons, sliders and wheels", therefore that MCU does fully work with the QTouch library.

Comment: of the same product page they Hardware QTouch Acquisition: NO , what does it mean to me ?

Comment: @Engine: That means that it's done in software, via the QTouch library.